# Python Time Spent using Remainder Modulo Operator

Tags: python

I'm stuck on creating this program that a person spends answering questions.

For the first question they spend 26 minutes.
For the further 3 questions they spend 12 minutes.

The output which I want displayed on screen is:

- The total number of minutes spent.
- The number of hours and minutes spent as whole numbers.

This is my current code and can't work out how the remainder function can be used.

Ideally, I'm trying to find a way I can do it without using the if statement.

```
answer = 26
additional_answers = 12
hour = 60
minutes_spent = answer + additional_answers

print(answer + additional_answers, " minutes spent")

if hour <= 60:
    print(0, "hours", + minutes_spent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division to get the number of hours, and modulus to get the minutes part.

```
total = answer + additional_answers
hours = total // 60
minutes = total % 60
print(total, " minutes spent")
print(hours, " hours, ", minutes, " minutes")
```

There's also a function `divmod` that performs both operation at once:

```
hours, minutes = divmod(total, 60)
```

Comment: Use divmod:
hours,minutes = divmod(total, 60)